# Можно ли с помощью только одного запроса INSERT INTO добавить данные сразу в 2 таблицы?

Tags: mysql, join, insert

Сразу скажу, что триггеры я ещё не изучал.
У меня тема JOIN.
По раздельности то добавить данные в 2 таблицы понятно как, что я и сделал. Но можно ли как-то провернуть это **одним** запросом с помощью **JOIN**?  Вряд ли на данном этапе будет задание просто с двумя *INSERT*'ами.
Исходные таблицы тут https://dbfiddle.uk/CooZGvBH
СУБД MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Решение в формате триггера.

Требуемый жанр передаётся в определённой пользователем переменной `@genres`.

В случае пакетной вставки всем записям, у которых жанр не задан либо задан неправильно, будет присвоен жанр из переменной.

Обрабатываются варианты:

- `id` жанра указан, и такой существует (триггер ничего не делает)
- `id` жанра указан, но такой не существует (обрабатывается, будто не указано)
- `id` жанра не указан, переданное в переменной название существует (подставляется соотв. значение)
- `id` жанра не указан, переданное в переменной название не существует (вставляется новая запись, подставляется её id)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_artists
BEFORE INSERT ON artists
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- проверка, что genre_id задано, причём правильно
IF (SELECT name FROM genres WHERE id = NEW.genre_id) IS NULL THEN
  -- проверка, что переданный в переменной @genre жанр отсутствует
  -- если он существует - вставляем соотв. значение-ссылку
  SET NEW.genre_id = (SELECT id FROM genres WHERE name = @genre);
  -- если не существует - вставляем запись и заполняем поле ссылки
  IF NEW.genre_id IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO genres (name) VALUES (@genre);
    SET NEW.genre_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END IF;
END IF;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O4fXP2Ng) (с дополнительными пояснениями)

Триггер не обрабатывает вариант, когда жанр не задан либо задан неправильно, и переменная `@genre` не имеет значения (содержит NULL). В этом случае в genres вставится запись с `name=NULL`. Однако по смыслу это поле **должно** быть определено как NOT NULL. Следует исправить структуру таблицы. Тогда описанный вариант приведёт к ошибке вставки, а не к вставке пустого значения. Если же "пустой" жанр легитимен и обозначает "не задано", замените простое сравнение на NULL-safe.

Если существуют дополнительные варианты - следует соотв. образом дополнить код.

PS. Значительную долю артистов относят обычно к более чем одному жанру. То есть должна быть связь много-ко-много и плюс связующая таблица. А там всё будет по-другому.

Comment: Да вот то, что с помощью триггера решается, я видел подобное, просто я их ещё не проходил и не вникал в этот метод. Спасибо за подробное чёткое пояснение, изучу в своё время

Comment: @61ack63rry Ну  а единственная альтернатива - это хранимая процедура. Формально запрос будет один - `call proc(..);`. Хотя внутри запросов будет больше (впрочем, при использовании триггера происходит то же самое).

Answer (score 0):

Не бывает такого, насколько я знаю. Единственное что можно сделать - сделать два `INSERT`-а через `;`.

```sql
INSERT INTO genres (name) VALUES ('Rap');
INSERT INTO artists (name, genre_id, is_group) VALUES ('Eminem', 6, False);
```

Comment: Ну я также сделал. Просто интересует, есть ли другой вариант